# ADO.Net Synchronization & SQL CE

Tags: sql, synchronization, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I've succesfully synchronized both source and local db using the local database cache item in VS 2008.

However, I need to access the SQL CE db directly from within another dll/process, and without using a dataset. The reason being that my business object code does not use datasets.

The final code wouldlook something like this:

```
Dim conn As New SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection("Data Source=C:\Development\UserDirectory\UserDirectory.DBSyncher\ProfDir.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;")
Dim cmd As New SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand("Select EmailAddress from Employees Where ID=23", conn)
Dim returnString As String = ""

If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    conn.Open()
End If
returnString = cmd.ExecuteScalar

conn.Close()
cmd = Nothing
```

I notice something very strange using a dataset the synchronized changes are shown but accessing the CE database file directly returns old data - no synched data whatsoever.

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please add tag 'sqlservercompactedition' for better search

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

Forgot that CE is in process, thus it copies the database file(.sdf) to the Debug folder. You have to to reference that database not the one in your project. DOH!